# Understand potential conflicts

Tags: parsing, ocaml, menhir

I have a small parser of expression built by Menhir. I'm trying to recover parenthesis-incomplete expressions during parsing by writing recovery grammars in `parser.mly`:

```
%{ 
   open AST
%}

%token<int> LINT 
%token<string> ID
%token LPAREN RPAREN COMMA
%token EOF PLUS STAR EQ

%start<AST.expression> expressionEOF

%right LPAREN RPAREN
%nonassoc EQ
%left PLUS
%left STAR

%%

expressionEOF: e=expression EOF
{
  e
}

expression:
| x=LINT
{
  Int x
}
| x=identifier
{
  Read x
}
| e1=expression b=binop e2=expression
{
  Binop (b, e1, e2)
}
| e1=expression b=binop
(* for "2+", "2*3+" *)
{
  Binop (b, e1, FakeExpression)
}
| LPAREN e=expression RPAREN
{
  Paren e
}
| LPAREN RPAREN
(* for "()" *)
{
  Paren FakeExpression
}
| LPAREN
(* for "(" *)
{
  ParenMissingRparen FakeExpression
}
| LPAREN e=expression 
(* for "(1", "(1+2", "(1+2*3", "((1+2)" *)
{
  ParenMissingRparen e
}
| RPAREN
(* for ")" *)
{
  ExtraRparen FakeExpression
}
| e=expression RPAREN 
(* for "3)", "4))", "2+3)" *)
{
  ExtraRparen e
}

%inline binop:
  PLUS { Add   }
| STAR { Mul   }
| EQ   { Equal }

identifier: x=ID
{
  Id x
}
```

It works fine on a set of incomplete expressions. However, `menhir --explain parser.mly` returns the following `parser.conflict`:

```
** Conflict (reduce/reduce) in state 10.
** Tokens involved: STAR RPAREN PLUS EQ EOF
** The following explanations concentrate on token STAR.
** This state is reached from expressionEOF after reading:

LPAREN expression RPAREN

** The derivations that appear below have the following common factor:
** (The question mark symbol (?) represents the spot where the derivations begin to differ.)

expressionEOF 
expression EOF 
expression STAR expression // lookahead token appears
(?)

** In state 10, looking ahead at STAR, reducing production
** expression -> LPAREN expression RPAREN
** is permitted because of the following sub-derivation:

LPAREN expression RPAREN . 

** In state 10, looking ahead at STAR, reducing production
** expression -> expression RPAREN
** is permitted because of the following sub-derivation:

LPAREN expression // lookahead token is inherited
       expression RPAREN . 

** Conflict (reduce/reduce) in state 3.
** Tokens involved: STAR RPAREN PLUS EQ EOF
** The following explanations concentrate on token STAR.
** This state is reached from expressionEOF after reading:

LPAREN RPAREN

** The derivations that appear below have the following common factor:
** (The question mark symbol (?) represents the spot where the derivations begin to differ.)

expressionEOF 
expression EOF 
expression STAR expression // lookahead token appears
(?)

** In state 3, looking ahead at STAR, reducing production
** expression -> LPAREN RPAREN
** is permitted because of the following sub-derivation:

LPAREN RPAREN . 

** In state 3, looking ahead at STAR, reducing production
** expression -> RPAREN
** is permitted because of the following sub-derivation:

LPAREN expression // lookahead token is inherited
       RPAREN .
```

I don't understand what it tries to explain. Could anyone tell me what may be potential conflicts (with example by preference) and what would be solutions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have:

```
expr: '(' expr ')'
    | '(' expr
    |     expr ')'
```

So, you want `( x )` to match the first rule:

```
         expr
      -> '('  expr ')'  (rule 1)
```

Which it does. But it also matches another way:

```
         expr
      -> expr       ')' (rule 3)
      -> '(' expr   ')' (rule 2)
```

And it also matches like this:

```
         expr
      -> '('   expr     (rule 2)
      -> '('   expr ')' (rule 3)
```

Since you also let `expr` match `(` and `)`, `( )` can also be matched several ways, including as `expr ')'` (with `expr -> '('`), or `'(' expr` (with `expr -> ')'`).

The "solution" is to give up trying to add recognition of invalid sentences. The parse should fail on a syntax error; once it fails you can try to use Menhir's error recovery mechanism to produce an error message and continue the parse. See section 11 of the manual.